# Avoid inline styling in jquery while appending elements dynamically?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm experimenting with jQuery and I made this [**fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/tk614cn4/). 
What it basically does is wherever you click, a `div` element is appended on the body to that clicked coordinates.

I've managed to do it but I would like to avoid the inline styling, i.e.; 
this line : `$('body').append('<div style="top:'+y+'px; left:'+x+'px;"></div>');`

Is there any way I could do this with any jQuery methods where the CSS can be set for every particular `div` as soon as it is appended?

Comment: do you want the same css for everything or different?

Comment: @Pratik I want to set `top` and `left` properties without using inline styling

Comment: Only reason I can think of for avoiding inline styles in this case is if you want to be able to identify these elements using an ID for other things. In which case you will need to give each new element an ID and manually add a CSS rule targeting said ID with the desired styles. Otherwise, I don't see how having inline styles is a problem.

Comment: You can't set those things using css. You have to make it inline. The css would not know about your mouse position at any point of time

Comment: What's the goal? To avoid using the `style` attribute at all? Or just to more easily/'readably' set the `top` and `left` properties? One alternative to use is this approach: [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/tk614cn4/1/), but I'm not sure this meets any part of your requirement since it does precisely the same thing, overall, just with a different approach to doing so.

Comment: @DavidThomas, yes that's the goal.

Comment: @BoltClock, using inline styling isn't a problem, I would like to have an alternative approach.

Comment: You can't avoid inline styling unless you want to make a class name in CSS for EVERY position on the screen... (1920x1080 = 2million+ classes).  You're better off doing what you're doing.  If you don't want to **add the inline styling when you append** you can always append the element then directly after give it a `.css({})` property.   But when you look at the code, it will look the same.  It will give an in-line style to your element

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it is to function as your fiddle does, stick with inline styles. To dynamically write CSS into a style tag in the dom for every element, while possible, would be [hyper-wonky](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/wonky).

If you like it more jQuery like, you can write it like this:

```
$('<div/>').css({'top' :y, 'left':x}).appendTo('body');
```

but that essentially does the same thing you're already doing.
[See it here](https://jsfiddle.net/tk614cn4/2/)

Comment: Even though an _Inspect Element_ on the resulting node would be the same for this and the OP `.append(...)` I _tremendously_ prefer this approach - create the node, style it, then append it.

Comment: are there performance implications for using this approach with a large number of elements?

Answer (score 1):

After appending all dynamic elements you can append a style tag directly to the head to avoid any inline style in your code.

E.g.:

```
$('head').append(
    '<style type="text/css">' + 
        'div{ top: y; left: x}' + 
    '</style>'
);
```

You can also use style sheets for performance purposes. See:  https://learn.jquery.com/performance/use-stylesheets-for-changing-css/